# Elasticsearch dynamic template with regex fails to work

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to create dynamic template which aim is to change data type of all fields inside index according to regular expression `/(fields.Account.*[a-zA-Z0-9_])/ig`. Meaning template should filter all the field names containing `fields.Account` and change their datatype to text. However the dynamic template below makes no intended impact at all.

```
`[
  {
    "Account": {
      "match_pattern": "regex",
      "mapping": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "match_mapping_type": "*",
      "match": "/(fields.Account.*[a-zA-Z0-9_])/ig"
    }
  }
]`
```

I definitely miss something. Please help me to find out what exactly.

I tried to play with different expressions but with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match` only operates on the final field name, not on nested fields.

You should use [path_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch) instead:

```
[
  {
    "Account": {
      "path_match": "fields.Account.*",
      "mapping": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but still without success. I also noted when I browse through "Mapping" section of my index I indeed see "dynamic_templates" section but along with some static mapping for target fields. Does Elastic automatically add it?

Comment: it is worth noting that once fields are created in an index mapping, there's no way to change them, you need to recreate your index with the dynamic mapping and reindex your old index into the new one. Just adding the dynamic template in your existing index will not change the mapping for existing fields, only for newly added ones

Comment: It’s completely new index. That’s why I’m confused

Comment: Do you mind sharing the full index mapping and a sample document?

Comment: Apologize but because of security reasons I can share only part of mapping:
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "Account": {
          "path_match": "fields.Account.*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "fields": {
        "properties": {
          "0": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Account": {
            "type": "long"
          },

Comment: Ok one issue I see is that `fields.Account` is not an object but a field of type long, so it's unlikely that you can create any more fields named `fields.Account.*` and you must have mapping exceptions in your client application when trying to do so

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I was sure it is possible to override field type using Elasticsearch tools. Dynamic templates for example

Comment: You cannot override or change fields that already exist in your mapping. In your case, `fields.Account` is a long, so I guess it's because the first document coming in has a long in that field, so it doesn't match the dynamic template, and then all fields called `fields.Account.*` cannot be created because a long is not an object, and hence, cannot contain any sub-fields

Comment: Cool, glad we made it!